# How do I know which file to edit in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, wordpress-theming

I have a website in WordPress and I've noticed in some points I want to change a piece of text or something similar, but I don't know which file to edit.

How do I locate the file that I want to edit using FTP (for example using FileZilla) in order to change the website detail that I want to?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, there's going to be more than one file. A good place to start is by looking at the class of the body tag. Generally it references which templates the page is using.

Comment: after looking the CSS classes, I try to find my path on this page : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

It's a very big topic to discuss.

- If you want to edit any content of the page you can edit page.php file which is located in your Theme folder e.g. (wp-content/themes/theme-name).
- If you want to edit any content related to post you can content.php which is again related to your theme folder.
- If you want to edit sidebar content edit sidebar-content.php file (located in your theme folder).

There are other templates as well. But all the template files are located in your theme folder.